# Convergence of the alternating $p$-series $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assuming $p>0$, we consider the $p$-series $$
1-\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}-\frac{1}{4^p}+\cdots
$$
For what $p$-values is the series convergent? For what $p$-values is the series absolutely convergent? Which $p$-values will make it is conditionally convergent?

Comment: Maybe [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) can help.

Comment: $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$ is conditionally convergent for any $s$ with positive real part and absolutely convergent for any $s$ with real part greater than one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Comment: This is a reasonable mathematical problem, but you've presented it without context.  If you have a genuine interest in the problem, it would likely be easy for you to articulate why it is interesting, what approaches or research you pursued before posting, or where you encountered the problem.  Such information would improve the body of your Question.

Answer (score 2):

If $p>0$, then the series is convergent by the [alternating test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) (a proof in the link).

If $p>0$, considering that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p} \right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}
$$ the latter series and the following integral are of the *same nature* ([a proof here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence))
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p}
$$ and there is a convergence *iff* $p>1$.

Thus there is a *conditional convergence* for $0<p\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

we will use the criteria for convergence of alternating series which involves following two conditions 1) (an) must be non-increasing sequence of positive terms 2) limit of an should be 0 as n tends to infinity(https://i.stack.imgur.com/on0xd.jpg)